# Create custom rendering of a field for search?

Tags: entities, search

Is there a way to change the appearance of a field in the search?

Using a custom plugin, there is a field that holds an ID linked to a media database. The usual display for this field is getting links to all the images in this collection specified with this id. They will then be rendered using JavaScript.

In the search, I want to only show a thumbnail of the first image.
How can I hook into the search result rendering to change the display of this field.

At the moment, it just displays the stored ID in JSON format directly from the database without any processing!

Comment: Why usual method (set different view mode of entire node for display, and use another field format in that mode) does not work for you, exactly?

Comment: Because I don't know how to create a different format, I guess. The rendering of the field is defined in the template `field--field_media_collection_reference.tpl.php`